# Bounded operator on $L^2(\Bbb R^2)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $\lambda\in \{z\in\Bbb C\mid \text{Re}(z)>0\quad \text{and}\quad \text{Im}(z)>0 \}$. Consider the operator $T_\lambda: L^2(\Bbb C)\to L^2(\Bbb C)$:
$$
f\mapsto T_\lambda(f)(z)=\int_{\Bbb C}f(z-w) \psi\left(  \frac{\lambda-\mu}{2\lambda},1,\frac{\lambda}{2}(|w|^2)\right)e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}\ (|w|^2\ ) - i\frac{\lambda}{2} \text{Im}(z\overline{w})}dw
$$

where  $dw=dxdy$ is the usual measure  Lebesgue on $\Bbb C$.
How to prove que $T_\lambda(f)\in L^2(\Bbb C)$ ?
Here: we have $\psi\left(  a,c,z\right)\sim z^{-a}$ as $z\to\infty$
$\psi$ is the Kummer funtion noted sometimes $U(a,b,c)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)

Thanks

Comment: What you've written doesn't seem to make sense. In the left-hand side, you have $T_\lambda f(x,y)$, which presumably means this is a function of $(x,y)$, but your right-hand side integral is over $(x,y)$.

Comment: You probably meant to write $du\ dv$. In that case, replace $u$ and $v$ by $x-u$ and $y-v$. Multiplying out, you see a leading term of $e^{-\frac\lambda 4(x^2+y^2)}$, which makes the funktion rapidly decreasing.

Comment: @ 
Matt Rosenzweig.@Echo: Yes it is dudvu

Comment: Why do you think it is bounded for non real $\lambda$?

Comment: beacuse it is a resolvent operator for an unbounded operator

Comment: It is better If you write down the operator and explain more. Do yuo have already a proof and seek for a simpler one?

Comment: Ok. I will write it. Thank you

Comment: @ 
Giorgio Metafune see above please

Comment: It is strange that I have not recieived the notification of your comment, so I see it now. As I said above, I do not see why $T_\lambda f \in L^2$ for complex $\lambda$ (even though the integral converges pointwise). The introduction of the $\psi$ function does not change much. You said that it is the resolvent of an operator; you should show which one is that and explain how you got the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I will only indicate the standard procedure to deal with such questions and leave the details to you.
First, showing that this function is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of course consists in estimating the $L^2$-norm,
$$ ||T_\lambda f||^2\leq \int \int |f(z-w) \psi(...) \exp(...)|^2 dw dz =\int \int |I(z,w)|^2 dw dz, $$
where $I(z,w)$ is the integrand. One then usually tries to "factorize" the function $I(z,w)$, i.e. $|I(z,w)|\leq I_1(z) I_2(w)$ with $I_1,I_2\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. For example, one standard trick is to shift the argument $z\mapsto z+w$ so that $f$ only depends on $z$. This usually works quite well in combination with the exponential function whose argument is a bilinear form for obvious reasons. Regarding $\psi$ the asymptotic $\psi(a,c,z)\sim z^{-a}$ implies the existence of a constant $C>0$ such that for $z$ large enough, $$ |\psi(a,c,z)|\leq C z^{-a}, $$ which shows that $\psi$ decreases quickly (if $a>0$, $z>0$ real) and hence should be no big problem.

I also would recommend to start with only considering $\lambda>0$ real so that one can at least guarantee that $\exp(-\lambda ||w||^2)$ falls exponentially fast and $|\exp(i\lambda r)|=1$ for any real number $r$ and go from there. Also, if you are not able to get finite estimates for your integral there is a good chance that what you have written down is not an $L^2$-function.

Comment: When $\lambda>0$. we have $|T_\lambda(f)(z)|\leq \int_{\Bbb C}|f(z-w)| | \psi\left(  \frac{\lambda-\mu}{2\lambda},1,\frac{\lambda}{2}(|w|^2)\right)e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}\ (|w|^2\ ) }|dw$. So the result is easy just by Young's convolution inequality

Comment: I think the question is more complicated